# SerializerMethodField for more than one fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This question might have an easier answer. But I don't get what it is. Please consider this example

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    a2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
```

With below `ModelBSerializer` I can get the values of the `a1` or `a2` of `ModelA` using the `SerializerMethodField` for `modela` field.

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modela = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = (
            'modela',
            'b2',
        )

    def get_b1(self, obj):
        return obj.modela.a1  # or obj.modela.a2
```

But What if I want both `a1` and `a2`? And I want them to be included in the `ModelBserializer` fields along with `modela` and `b2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`source`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument as below,

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modela = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    a1 = serializers.CharField(source='modela.a1')
    a2 = serializers.CharField(source='modela.a2')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('b2', 'modela', 'a1', 'a2')
```

The [**`StringRelatedField()`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) return the **`__str__`** represantation **`modela`** class